# TDD unit tests can call other functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I've discovered TDD on Python using the excellent book ([Test Driven Development in Python](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/)), and so far, I'm enjoying it.

However, I've a question regarding the way you create Unit test.

Let's imagine something like this :

```
def A(MyObject):
    # Do some complex modification on MyObject
    return modified_MyObject

def B(modified_MyObject):
    # Do some stuff on modified_MyObject
    return something
```

If I want to test A, it'll be pretty simple : I'll create a object manually in my unit test, and test it, something like this :

```
class TestObject(unittest.TestCase):

    def testA(self):
        testA = MyObject()
        modified_MyObject = A(testA)
        # assert MyObject has been modified
```

However, how to test B ?
I can see to way :

- creating manually a "modified_MyObject" and use it to test B
- using A() in testB() to create a modified_MyObject

The first method allows testB not be dependent of A(), but I will then create a "constant" object, which is apparently something to avoid in TDD. Moreover, if I changed something in my code, I'll have to modify also my created object. Finally, if the modification done on my object implies hundreds of steps / data, it can be a real pain to create the object by hand.

The second method is making a dependance between A() & testB, but as I'm testing also A(), it should be ok.

```
    def testB(self):
        testA = MyObject()
        testModifiedObject = A(testA)
        result = B(testModifiedObject)
        # assert that B return a correct result.
```

The general question could be : "in TDD, if code functions are using other functions, can I use them as well in my unit tests ?"

Thanks for your help,

Comment: as a general rule, tests should be independent. So it is better to create object again in different test, unless it is really expensive (but if it is, it should rather be handled by integration tests).

Comment: So basically, you are saying quite the opposite as @Duncan. It's kind of confusing :/

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too general, can you give a concrete example? The answer is going to be different depending on the objects and relationships.

In general however, yes you can use other functions (so long as those functions have their own tests). Usually you would do this in a `setUp` method:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.modified_object = A(object())

def testB(self):
    result = B(self.modified_object)
    # assert something
```

Sometimes though you might want a mock object or just pass some dummy object to B. It all depends.

BTW, you do know that an object created by `object()` is immutable, you cannot modify it?

Comment: As for a concrete example, it's pretty much what I've wirtten in my question : creating an object, modify it and use the modified object in another function.

Thanks for your answer, you're conforting me in my choice of using other (already testded) functions in my tests, and not creating constants.